# Does synchronization allow visibility to all variables after synchronized method call?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public class Test {
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

public synchronized void setAB(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public synchronized int getA() {
    return a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}
```

---

Thread-1 calls setAB(1,5) -  sets value of a and b atomically.

Thread-2 calls getA() - synchronized access. this calls establishes happens before relationship with above one. thread should be able to see updated value for a.

Thread-2 calls getB() - this is non-synchronized call. will it see updated for b i.e. 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general for the getB() call there is no "happens before relationship", no visibility guarantee. It is important to synchronize both reads and writes, and to synchronize them **on the same lock**.

However, if getB() is called after getA() in the same thread, then the "happens before relationship" has already been established, and the thread is guaranteed to see all changes.

It is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description) (with my added emphasis):

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And **because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.**